# Pushing data to web-hosted database (SQL Server)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, winforms, remote-access, database-replication

I have a client who wants to maintain both a local winforms price list installed in their office PCs and an online price list (web hosted app with SQL Server) accessible to their customers. Problem is they don't want to fully migrate their local database online and now I need to find a way to push their data to the online database on a daily basis.

My question is - is there a way to remotely connect to a SQL Server database and update the online pricelist using my client's winforms app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Construct  your [connectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) for remote database.

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping for a remote database setup guide for MSSQL.